# Can't run dockerized .NET Core (3.1) API

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Build
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

Building it for the first time, I had this error:

> error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

And I solved it adding

```
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
```

to my .csproj, then I could build it.

At this point, when trying to run it with

```
docker run -p 8082:8080 --rm dockerized-app:dev
```

Docker throws this error:

> The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/app/'.

Looking for a solution on internet I found that I could solve it adding

```
<GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
```

to the .csproj, which I did, built again, and when running I'm getting this error which I can't solve:

> Entry point not found in assembly 'myapp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

EDIT: Adding the actual code of the API.

Controller.cs:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class MyAppController : ControllerBase
    {
        [EnableCors("AllowOrigin")]
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetText(Request request)
        {
            return request.text;
        }
    }
```

Program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Startup.cs:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders",
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                                 .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(builder =>
            {
                builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
            });

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58726",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "myapp",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MyApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchUrl": "myapp",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

myapp.csproj (with the changes I mentioned before):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Newtonsoft.Json" />
    <None Remove="Models\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Models\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And, just in case someone asks, it works locally, it starts and wait for receiving a request.

Comment: We'll probably need to see some code. How was the project generated? Was it Visual Studio or via the `dotnet` CLI?

Comment: If your program doesn't have a static Main function, how do you expect it to run anything? You can't run a class library.

Comment: @MattU The project has been generated through Visual Studio IDE. The code is just an API which has a single endpoint in the controller. Just updating my post with the code.

Comment: @HansKilian It's an API, isn't supposed to "run" anything itself, it's just sitting there waiting for a request.

Comment: That's also running something. If you create a webapi project from a template, the template creates a Program.cs file that has a static Main function in it. It sounds like your project doesn't have that which seems wrong.

Comment: @HansKilian Yes yes, it has a Program.cs just haven't updated the post when answered you yet, now you got it there sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only copy the .csproj file into the image. You're missing the step where you copy the rest of the files.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# vvvv   This is missing
COPY . .

# Build
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it's still throwing the errors I mentioned in the post, tried with all the configs on .csproj.

Comment: Have you changed back the stuff you changed to try to solve it, like the OutputType in the csproj file?

Comment: Quitting all the stuff I added and leaving it as it was, it works!! you're a genius. Now I got another problem, my front doesn't connect with the API, but that's another post I guess right? Well thank you so much!!